# Enable rewrite for a particular host in ingress nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have below ingress-nginx configuration file.

It rewrites request for `one.example.com`. I have added another domain, but I don't want rewrite to happen for other domain.

I went through doc, but there is now rewrite example for multiple host setup.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-example-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - one.example.com
        - two.example.com
      secretName: super-secret
  rules:
    - host: one.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /customer/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: customer-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
      host: two.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: kube-prometheus-grafana
              port:
                number: 80
```

I could create two separate ingress files for each host.

What will happen in that case it will create two load balancers with different dns?

(cluster is hosted on aws)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two separate ingress.

In that case, nothing will change your ingress **controller IP** would be same only for DNS.

> What will happen in that case it will create two load balancers with
> different dns?

No, it won't create two load balancers.

Comment: Thanks @Harsh, Will it create two load balancer?

Comment: No it won't create LB. Only one LB will be there of your ingress controller.

Comment: Should I have same for each file `metadata.name:  ingress-service`. Will there be any issue?

Comment: No it will overwrite the existing one you have to use another name.

Comment: great glad to hear that.